# Asp.Net MVC LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 login is failling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

LinkedIn login has stopped working suddenly with error code **error=access_denied**, without any change in codebase or package.

As per documentation error code **access_denied**, means user has has declined permission but it's happening even on giving permission and we request only the default information email id.

The issue is that the user information returned is always null.

Nuget package used is **Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn** : 2.22.0, we tried to update it but it did not fix the issue.

For diagnosis we checked the linkedIn app setting it looks fine, also **login works via javascript sdk** for same app id, so issue does not seems to be with app id.

There is no issue raised related to it in github. So, not sure where is the root issue.

Any pointer or solution to the issue will be helpful.

Comment: what version is MVC? 5 or core 2?

Comment: what is old version number of Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn? have you tried downgrade to old version? here is change log, where you can check if any changes rely on login: https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/commits/master

Comment: @Dongdong, it's a asp.net MVC 5 application. Need to check version of Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn. Yes, in the downgraded version also it did not work (which used to work), hence tried to update to see if any fix in any version.

Debugging seems to be the only way. Lets see if any one else has also faced this issue.

Comment: @Dongdong, linkedIn version is 2.22.0. Login not working in both this version and after update

Comment: @Dongdong issue resolved after debugging source code of package. It was due to a SecurityProtocol error. Thanks for pointing in that direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the issue after debugging the source code of nuget package Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders.

The call to end point https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken was failing due to tls negotiation issue and was throwing **The underlying connection was closed** error in method AuthenticateCoreAsync of LinkedInAuthenticationHandler class.
I set the SecurityProtocol as shown in below snippet.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Not sure why the call to this end point only failed suddenly though other end points were working.